# Spark SSD on Azure

Tags: azure, apache-spark

According to the official [Azure Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-perf#use-the-cache) using native Spark caching, even with disk persistence, won't take advantage of local SSD. I suspect that in order to benefit from it we need to use *OFF_HEAP* option when persisting RDDs. But then how to configure it so it uses local SDD (mounted as SDB1 under /mnt) and Alluxio for in-memory stuff? I know switches

```
--conf spark.memory.offHeap.enabled="true" \
--conf spark.memory.offHeap.size=10G \
```

I'm asking about datasets generated through a set of operations rather than generated from input datasets (which would be easy - they only "HDFS://" prefix is needed).

Answer (score 0):

To persist Data from Spark to a shared external storage that can manage SSD resource, you can use [Alluxio](https://alluxio.io). Spark can save and load RDDs or Dataframes to Alluxio easily:

```scala
// Save RDD to Alluxio as Text File
scala> rdd.saveAsTextFile("alluxio://master:19998/myRDD")
// Load the RDD back from Alluxio as Text File
scala> sc.textFile("alluxio://master:19998/myRDD")            

// Save Dataframe to Alluxio as Parquet files
scala> df.write.parquet("alluxio://master:19998/path")
// Load Dataframe back from Alluxio as Parquet files
scala> df = sqlContext.read.parquet("alluxio://master:19998/path")
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe they meant storing data explicitly to Alluxio or Hdfs directly?

e.g. instead of:

```
df.cache()
```

use write and read:

```
df.write.parquet("alluxio://master:19998/out.parquet")
df.read.parquet("alluxio://master:19998/out.parquet")
```

p.s. sorry for a stupid answer, wanted to write it in a comment but hadn't enough reputation.